# azure pipeline to delete the old azure git branch(not repo)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-repos

I am trying to create a azure pipeline to delete the old azure git branch(not repo).

So that creating an automated pipeline which will take bellow parameters.

1. Project Name
2. Repo Name
3. Target date

Based on input provided, all branches created before the target date for the given repo should be deleted.
Note :- We will only delete the child branch not master.

Rules

Only branches should be deleted on the basis be dry run flag if flag is true delete all branches in repo within given target date excluding master branch.

It’s better if we can write the code in python.

I am using rest azure rest api to call the branch but not able to delete as per date parameters.

```
import requests
import sys
from datetime import datetime as dt
import json
from git import Repo
import git
import time

username = '<u name>'
auth_key = '<auth key>'

class gitRepoDeletion:

    def getRepo(self, organization_name, project_name, repo_name):
        """
        Getting the repo details
        from the user and
        flitering the master
        branch with date functionality(still implementing)
        """
        getting_repo_list = "https://dev.azure.com/" + organization_name + '/' + \
            project_name + "/_apis/git/repositories/" + repo_name + "/refs?api-version=5.0"

        get_reponse = requests.get(
            getting_repo_list, auth=(username,auth_key))

        try:
            repojson = json.loads(get_reponse.content)
        except ValueError:
            print("Error loading json file")
        output_json = [x for x in repojson['value']
                       if x['name'] != 'refs/heads/master']
        with open('/home/vsts/work/1/s/data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(output_json, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

    def filtering_branches(self, organization_name, project_name, repo_name, user_date):
        """ 
        Filtering branches according 
        to the date passed by user

        """

        git_url = "https://" + organization_name + "@dev.azure.com" + '/' + \
            organization_name + '/' + project_name + '/_git' + '/' + repo_name

        branches = Repo.clone_from(git_url, "./mylocaldir209")

        remote_branches = []
        for ref in branches.git.branch('-r').split('\n'):
            if ref != '  origin/HEAD -> origin/master':
                if ref != '  origin/master':
                    remote_branches.append(ref[9:])
                else:
                    pass

        branch_and_timing_dict = {}

        for listy in remote_branches:
            branches.git.checkout(listy)
            commit = branches.head.commit
            timing = time.asctime(time.gmtime(commit.committed_date))
            timing = time.strftime(
                "%d/%m/%Y", time.gmtime(commit.committed_date)).replace(' 0', ' ')
            branch_and_timing_dict[listy] = timing

        global filterlist
        filterlist = []

        for key, values in branch_and_timing_dict.items():
            d1 = dt.strptime(user_date, "%d/%m/%Y") 
            d2 = dt.strptime(key, "%d/%m/%Y")
            if d1 > d2:
                filterlist.append(values)
            else:
                pass
        return filterlist

    def repo_delete(self, organization_name, project_name, repo_name, dry_flag):
        """
        Deleting repo as
        per date input by user
        also exlucling master

        """

        all_repo_to_be_deleted = []

        newObjectId = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

        filteredBranchesAsPerDateWithRef = []
        
        for value in filterlist:
            filteredBranchesAsPerDateWithRef.append("refs/heads/" + value)
            print(value)
        print(filteredBranchesAsPerDateWithRef)

        # Cluttering extra spaces and lowering the case of the dry flag value passed by the user

        # Reading data.json file, which is fetched by the getRepo() method after excluding the master branch
        with open('/home/vsts/work/1/s/data.json') as data_file:
            json_data = json.load(data_file)
        for item in json_data:
            name_of_branch = item['name']
            objectId = item['objectId']
            # Adding name_of_branch in all_repo_to_be_deleted list
            all_repo_to_be_deleted.append(name_of_branch)
            # Adding objectId in all_repo_to_be_deleted list
            # all_repo_to_be_deleted.append(objectId)
            passing_branch_name = "https://dev.azure.com/" + organization_name + '/' + \
                project_name + "/_apis/git/repositories/" + repo_name + "/refs?api-version=5.0"
            headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

        for nameOfBranchWithref in filteredBranchesAsPerDateWithRef:
            print(nameOfBranchWithref)
            nameOfBranchWithref = nameOfBranchWithref

            data = [
                {
                    "name": nameOfBranchWithref,
                    "newObjectId": newObjectId,
                    "oldObjectId": objectId,
                }
            ]

            dry_flag = dry_flag.lower().strip()
            if dry_flag == 'true':
                repo_delete = requests.post(passing_branch_name, data=json.dumps(
                    data), headers=headers, auth=(username, auth_key))
                print(repo_delete)

            else:
                with open('delete_repo.txt', 'w') as d:
                    for item in all_repo_to_be_deleted:
                        d.write("%s\n" % item)
                print("---- This is Dry Run ----")
                print("These are the repo to be deleted: ", all_repo_to_be_deleted)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gitRepoDeletion().getRepo('sushmasureshyadav202', 'my_delete_git', 'my_delete_git')
    
    gitRepoDeletion().filtering_branches(
        "<azure org name>", '<azure project>', '<azure repo>', "31/1/2020")
    gitRepoDeletion().repo_delete("<azure org name>", '<azure project>', '<azure repo>', 'true')
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service. what have you tried, what doesnt work?

Comment: all thing is working except user input not working in azure pipeline which i had took as hard code. please see the complete code.

Comment: Please update the question using the edit function instead of adding your follow-up in the textbox below. StackOverflow captures everything that belongs to the question in one place and then allows people to add their potential solutions below. Instead of the standard back-and-forth you see in forums, people are encouraged to update their questions or finetune the answers.

Answer (score 1):

> all thing is working except user input not working in azure pipeline
>   which i had took as hard code.

For the user input (input credentials ), please reference below sample:

```
import requests
import base64

repo_endpoint_url = "https://dev.azure.com/<organization>/<project>/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.1"

username = "" # This can be an arbitrary value or you can just let it empty
password = "<your-password-here>"
userpass = username + ":" + password
b64 = base64.b64encode(userpass.encode()).decode()
headers = {"Authorization" : "Basic %s" % b64} 

response = requests.get(repo_endpoint_url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code) # Expect 200
```

You can also try using the PAT or OAuth token `$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` directly (use PAT or $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN to replace the `password`).

However, to enable your script to use the build pipeline OAuth token, we need to go to the **Options** tab of the build pipeline and select `Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token`.
[image]